# No apply function found when trying to convert a case class (derived from Trait) to Json

Tags: json, scala

I am struggling with a request to JSON conversion.

Error : No apply function found for CommonRequest

**ClassA.scala**

```
trait CommonRequest{
   //def someFunc()
   //val a: String
 }
    
object CommonRequest {
    implicit val CommonRequestRequestFormat: OFormat[CommonRequest] = Json.format[CommonRequest] // Error: No apply function found for CommonRequest
 }
```

**ClassB.scala**

```
case class DerivedRequestA(One: Int) extends CommonRequest{
  //Overridden def and vals
}

case class DerivedRequestB(Two: Int) extends CommonRequest{
  //Overridden def and vals
}

object DerivedRequestA {
  implicit val RequestAFormat: OFormat[DerivedRequestA] = Json.format[DerivedRequestA]
}

object DerivedRequestB {
  implicit val RequestAFormat: OFormat[DerivedRequestB] = Json.format[DerivedRequestB]
}
```

**ClassC.scala**

```
def CallAPI(request: CommonRequest): Future[CommonResponse] = {
    //call api with JSON request body
    request_body = toJsonStringValue(request) // This call needs write implicit
}

def toJsonStringValue[T](o: T)(implicit t: Writes[T]): String = {
  Json.toJson(o).toString()
}
```

Looks like, only companion object is not enough. What else I need to do here ?

Comment: You need to indicate which lib is used. BTW provided import in a standalone reproducer in recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The `toJson` method generates JSON based on the compile-time type of the object that is passed to it. In this case that type is `CommonRequest` which is a `trait` with no members or constructor, so the library has no way to read or write this.

To work properly the compiler needs to see the specific type of the object to be converted. This (totally untested) code may be what you want:

```
def CallAPI[T <: CommonRequest](request: T): Future[T] = {
   request_body = toJsonStringValue(request)
   // ...
}
```

This will call `toJsonStringValue` with the exact type of the `request` value, rather than the superclass type `CommonRequest`.

Comment: Still I am getting this error : No apply function found for CommonRequest. And it is pointing to the companion object of the Trait.

Comment: In which case you are calling `CallAPI` with a value of type `CommonRequest`. You need to preserve the actual request type all the way through the code.

Comment: The alternative is to write a custom `writes` handler for `CommonRequest` that checks the type and does the right thing, or just check the request type explicitly in `CallAPI`.